# How to pronounce 0.11％ in Japanese?

Tags: pronunciation

Sometimes I heard people refer 0.11% as

> レイテン　イチイチ　パーセント

While others believe

> レイテン　ジュウイチ　パーセント

is more correct.

Which version is more popularly accepted?

Comment: `others believe レイテン　ジュウイチ　パーセント is more correct` -- I wonder how they read 0.111111111...

Comment: “Zero point eleven percent” is not a correct expression *mathematically*. I highly doubt that any language officially expresses the number that way.

Comment: @droooze Doubt all you want, but there are languages which do. In all the Scandinavian languages, for example, it would be **very** unusual to pronounce _0,11%_ as anything other than _nul komma elleve procent_ (using Danish as an example). Nobody would ever say _nul komme et et_. Even in English, where decimals tend towards individual readings, this does not hold for currency decimals: something may cost _ten ninety-five_ or _ten fifty_, but never _ten nine five_ or _ten five oh_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you. I don't know about Scandinavian languages, but that English example is not valid - the 95 in $10.95 refers to ninety-five cents. In a standard decimal representation of a number, things after the decimal point don't refer to whole numbers of anything.

Comment: (This comment is also about Japanese, sorry for the long start). To Janus, just speculating, but could it just be that it happens to be easier to pronounce? Do you do the same with your halvfjerds? Would you still follow the same logic? And, any French people around, you have your peculiarities, so maybe you would actually use quatre-vingt-dix-neuf in case of 0.99% ;) ? Today a JAL pilot had 0.18 mg/l and I think one would use コッマジュウハチ (maybe even NHK, but I will check + come back on that). People also in Japan are pragmatic; therefore comma [omitting the zero] .

Comment: @droooze Vietnamese for example do that. The 23 in 0,23 is read just like the integer 23. Another example is German: 0,12 is read as *Null Komma zwölf*, lit. zero comma twelve, but spelling the digits separately is also acceptable

Comment: Looks like all these examples are exclusively for 2 decimal place readings, which seems to be the case, because 100th divisions are internationally common. Such readings still seem to be unsustainable if you go any more than that: surely 0.1334 is not read as “zero point one thousand three hundred and thirty four” in any of the aforementioned languages.

Comment: I promised to come back on how the JAL pilot blood alcohol content was reported, but it didn't make to the evening news (I guess since a half-Japanese runner Sani Brown broke the 100m Japan record, and got the media exposure. The time was reported, not using a テン　but saying  キュウビョウキュウジュウジャナナ also this didn't help this case).

Comment: ^ @Tuomo `キュウビョウキュウジュウジャナナ` ←?? 「ジャ」って？ 「9秒97」は「キュウビョウ**キュウナナ** 」です。→ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhHOa_X2PJE

Comment: @Tuomo `0.18 mg/l and I think one would use コッマジュウハチ` ← 「コ**ン**マジュウハチ」ですか？ 普通は「呼気１リットルあたりレイテン**イチハチ**ミリグラム」って言います。→ http://www.news24.jp/nnn/news162132634.html

Comment: @Chocolate, feel ashamed (again) and greatful for you valuable comments! Too hastly comments (although I really didn't know that "comma" is written as コンマ (thanks!), and I am quite used to the コンマ<decimals> way of reading values between 0 and 1 but I was also thinking that it might not be used in NHK news).

Comment: @droooze, not only in the Scandinavian languages, but in Spanish it is very usual to express numbers such as  0.11% as "zero ten eleven percent" as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-checked this with a native speaker, and they said it’s definitely レイテン　イチイチ　パーセント — the other one would be understandable but strange.

Comment: When is it preferred to use 零 versus ゼロ?